# Application url is ..index.html#/signup instead of ..index.html/#/signup

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013

I'm building an AngularJS(1.4.7) app. My signup url supposed to be `....index.html/#/signup`. But when I click signup link it shows  `....index.html#/signup`. And my signup view is not loading when I click signup button.

My app.js file: http://pastebin.com/ZHZkUV7m 
My index.html file: http://pastebin.com/SAkyYAWu 
My indexController:

```
'use strict'
app.controller('indexController', ['$scope', '$location', 'authService', function ($scope, $location, authService) {
    $scope.logot = function () {
        authService.logot();
        $location.path('/home');
    };
    $scope.authentication = authService.authentication;
}]);
```

Actually I'm playing with this blog post: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very minimal, yet working example of to implement `ngRoute`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/dxo3ZUJIWLeFw9HXF80w

**JavaScript**

```
  angular.module('testModule', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/foo', {
              template: '<p>Foo</p>'
          })
          .when('/bar', {
              template: '<p>Bar</p>'
          })
          .when('/baz', {
              template: '<p>Baz</p>'
          })
          .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/index.html'
          });
    }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <a href="#foo">Go to foo</a><br>
   <a href="#bar">Go to bar</a><br>
   <a href="#baz">Go to baz</a><br>
   <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Though this is not the answer but it helps me to find out the mistake I've made in route configuration. Actually it should be `templateUrl` not `urlTemplate`